# How can i add my changes to localhost web?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, model-view-controller, localhost

I'm working with an asp project, and I'm trying to add new changes on the inetpub folder, but it doesn't work.
I know that the inetpub folder is just for static files.

I'm just taking the .aspx file, but I made the changes on the .aspx.cs file.
How can I see that changes?

Comment: Did you recompile?

Comment: Yes, I did it, I will try again

Comment: Did you copy the newly compiled assembly to the bin folder?

Comment: It sounds like you need to take a tutorial. That said, you're using WebForms and that's practically dead now. Unless you need that for work (where a more senior developer should be helping you with this), you're better off learning the latest stuff. Furthermore, there are much simpler ways of publishing a web site, ensuring that everything gets updated that needs to be. Manually copying files like you are is fertile ground for mistakes.

Comment: That's the point, there is no dev above and the project has been done this way for some time. 
The bin folder has only the .dll and .pdb

Comment: The .cs files are compiled into the .dll file. You really need some C# and WebForms tutorials, and your company really needs to invest in at least one person with experience in this area. Asking questions at every roadblock is not going to get you the amount of knowledge that you need to support an existing, outdated application.

Comment: I tried with the dlls files, and it works, thank you so much!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Well, how this works depends on 2 details.

Are you using a asp.net web site?

or

Are you using a asp.net web site application?

So, depending on which of the above choices you made, then this will determine your options and how you have to update the web site.

For a asp.net web site? Then in most cases, you can simple deploy the aspx page, and also the code behind file. (both files have to be copied to the web server). At that point, you quite much done.

However, if you using a asp.net web site "application"? Then you have to re-deploy the WHOLE web site, and even for one tiny line of code you change. While this is "more work" or "more effort"?

The benefits of choosing a web site "application" are a far better choice. Not only do you enjoy far better compile time resolution and checking of your code, but you can also include multiple projects into that single project. Also, when using this kind of project, then ONLY the aspx page and the compiled code (into. dll’s) is to be placed on the web server. Thus, there are no source code files (the c# or vb.net files never are placed on the server).

So, to update the web site then, as a general rule you use the web site publish option. In fact, in most cases, I just publish to a local folder, and then zip up that folder, and transfer that zip file to the web server.

You then transfer that file to the web server. Stop the web server (so the files in question can be overwritten, and then simple copy all the files (from your un-zipped folder) into the given wwwroot folder of your site.

You then re-start the web server.

So how you update the site will depend on what kind of site you have (or choose) to work with. As noted, most if not all developers prefer the "application" choice, since then the standard build, compile and project works like near any other project So, to open such an application, then from VS you use file -> open project. (and select the .sln project file).

For a web site, the you use file->open web site.

As noted, while the web site option makes simple updates less effort, I find that as a developer too many compromises exist without being able to enjoy a valid visual studio project.

However, you do then have to use the VS publish option, and not just some copy of a the aspx page + the code page.